# Analytic Bounds for Eigenvalues of a 2x2 Block Matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, numerical-linear-algebra

I am trying to find conditions under which all eigenvalues of M will have nonpositive real part (i.e. M is negative semidefinite, I think).

$$M = \begin{bmatrix}
A & BE^T\\
CE & D\\
\end{bmatrix}$$

- A and B are $n\times n$ and diagonal with negative diagonal entries.
- C is $m \times m$ and diagonal  with positive diagonal entries.
- D is $m \times m$ and diagonal (I know if the diagonal entries were all negative, I could start with Gershgorin disks. Alas, they are not.)
- E is $m \times n$ and each row has two nonzero entries: +1 and -1.

Is there any way to do this? $LU$ and $LDU$ decompositions can be obtained easily using the Shur complement, but I can't figure out how to proceed from there. Online, I can only find conditions if $BE^T = (CE)^T$.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Note that $M$ is positive definite if and only if $M + M^T$ is positive definite.  So, it suffices to look at the eigenvalues of 
$$
M + M^T = \pmatrix{A & BE^T + E^TC\\ EB + CE & D}
$$
which is, conveniently enough, symmetric.

Comment: At the very least, note that if $A$ or $D$ have any negative entries, $M$ is automatically *not* positive semidefinite.

Comment: Actually, since you know that $A$ has negative entries, $M$ is automatically never positive semidefinite.  Double-check your conditions on $A$ and update accordingly.

Comment: @Narasimham it was clearer before you "fixed" it. Diagonal matrices are, by usual definitions, never negative.

Comment: OK, thanks I stand corrected about the diagonal sign convention..

Comment: Sorry, I think I meant negative semidefinite. I have edited the question to clarify. Is that possible? (Also, how do you know the $M + M^T$ condition, and does that also apply to negative (semi)definiteness?) Thank you!

Comment: Note that $x^TMx >0$ iff $x^TM^Tx >0$ (just taking transpose) and now add up these two. Now notice that same happens for negative definite also.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom, Can you explain please how $A$ or $D$ having any negative entries implies $M$ is not positive semidefinite.

Comment: @Sry plug in standard basis vectors for $x$

Comment: @Matrix_Help $M$ is negative definite if and only if $-M$ is positive definite, so all the same tricks work. I think that "all eigenvalues have negative real part" is more general than negative definite, though.